# Ajax not populatig dropdown if selected to fast

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a filter with two dropdowns, one with shows and another with their locations. When a show is selected in the first dropdown the list of locations in the second dropdown gets modified to contain only the locations where that particular show is played. Now the problem I have is that if a user clicks the locations dropdown to fast after selecting a show, it sometimes updates only after the user made a selection modifying the list and thus removing their selection  (This happens often in edge). Is there a way to update the list in the locations dropdown faster? Or atleast force it to update even though it is selected?

This the JavaScript I am using, it uses the 'example_ajax_request' function wich I have added to functions.php in Wordpress you can see it below the script.

```
 $('#select_show').change( function(){
        var show = $("#select_show :selected").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action':'example_ajax_request',
                'show' : show
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data) {
                console.log("what is happening al of a sudden");
                console.log(data);
                $('#province').children('option').remove();

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    if( data[i] == 'Choose a province')
                        var value = "all";
                    else
                        var value = data[i];

                    $('#province').append( $("<option value=" + value +"></option>").text(data[i]) );
                }

            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });

    });
```

My function wich gets the list of locations(provinces)

```
 function example_ajax_request() {

    $arrayList = array();
    $arrayList[] = "Choose a province";

    $selected = $_POST['show'];

    if( $selected == "Choose a show" )
        $selected = "";

    $arg = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'address',
        'meta_key' => 'show',
        'meta_value' => $selected,
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $arg );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() )
    {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() )
        {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $arrayList = get_option_list('province', $arrayList);
        }
    }
    print json_encode($arrayList);
    wp_reset_query();

    die();
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

And these are the dropdowns and their queries

```
    <?php
     $arg = array(

    'post_type' => 'address',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'show',
    'meta_value' => ''
     );

     $the_query = new WP_Query( $arg );

     $showlist = array();

     if( $the_query->have_posts() )
     {
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() )
     {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $showlist = get_option_list('show', $showlist);
     }
     }


     $arg = array(


    'post_type' => 'address',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'show',
    'meta_value' => '',
     );

     $the_query = new WP_Query( $arg );

     $provincelist = array();

     if( $the_query->have_posts() )
     {
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $provincelist = get_option_list('province', $provincelist);
    }
    }

    ?>

    <div class="block-go-to">
    <form action="reserve-tickets" method="get">
      <select id="select_show" name="show">
          <option value="all">Choose a show</option>
            <?php
                foreach($showlist as $show)
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $show; ?>">
                        <?php echo $show; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <select id="province" name="province">
            <option value="all">Choose a province</option>
            <?php
            foreach($provincelist as $province)
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $province; ?>">
                    <?php echo $province; ?>
                </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <button id="show_map" class="cta right">Show map</button>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['province']))
    $_SESSION['province'] = $_POST['province'];
?>
```

Comment: you could work around that problem by disabling your dropdown while it's fetching the locations for exemple

Comment: Look it's not possible to maintain user's selection without any effort that if user selects the location to fast before the ajax request's response. What you can do is disable the location dropdown until it gets updated and then again enable it to allow user selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this just as you enter the change event of your `#select_show` select

```
$('#province').attr('disabled', true);
```

this will disable the select, meaning the user won't be able to click on it manually (this is open to javascript hacks, tho).
Then when you're sure all your locations have been fetched, just turn it back to false

```
$('#province').attr('disabled', false);
```

which will of course re-enable the input to let the user use it.

note that there's probably alot of other ways to work around that problem, but that way was just the first that came up to my mind!

Comment: This is what I'd do too, although I recommend just for clarity adding to your answer what this does and how it solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I did. Although I had to use .prop for it to work.